# What is purpose of these tag? Where / when and how to use main-Axis_Alignment & cross_Axis_Alignment?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

how to use main-Axis-Alignment and cross-Axis-Alignment?
In the flutter interviews, this is the 1st question!

where to use main-Axis-Alignment and cross-Axis-Alignment?

What is the purpose of main-Axis-Alignment  the purpose of  and cross-Axis-Alignment tags

Answer (score 0):

For Row:

Horizontal Axis cross

AxisAlignment = Vertical Axis
[image]

For Column:

mainAxisAlignment = Vertical Axis

crossAxisAlignment = Horizontal Axis
[image]